# How do "pip install rdpy"

Tags: python-3.x, pip, installation, rdp, python-3.8

I need some help to install rdpy. Windows 10(x64),I also have local administrator rights on the computer. 
I have the following problem(error):

```
    Running setup.py install for rdpy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\dlbotov\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dlbotov\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i13r_bk2\\rdpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file_
_='"'"'C:\\Users\\dlbotov\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i13r_bk2\\rdpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '
"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dlbotov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-eexckv_3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\dlbotov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Py
thon38\Include\rdpy'
         cwd: C:\Users\dlbotov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i13r_bk2\rdpy\
    Complete output (69 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rdpy
    copying rdpy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rdpy
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rdpy\core
    copying rdpy\core\const.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rdpy\core
    ...
    ...
    copying rdpy\protocol\rfb\rfb.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rdpy\protocol\rfb
    copying rdpy\protocol\rfb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rdpy\protocol\rfb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rdpy\ui
    copying rdpy\ui\qt4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rdpy\ui
    copying rdpy\ui\view.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rdpy\ui
    copying rdpy\ui\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rdpy\ui
    running build_ext
    building 'rle' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\ext
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\dlbotov\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\dlbotov
\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\1
4.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Progr
am Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcext/rle.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64
-3.8\Release\ext/rle.obj
    rle.c
    ext/rle.c(930): warning C4244: дг­ЄжЁп: ЇаҐ®Ўа §®ў ­ЁҐ "Py_ssize_t" ў "int", ў®§¬®¦­  Ї®вҐап ¤ ­­ле
    ext/rle.c(945): warning C4013: Py_InitModule: ­Ґв ®ЇаҐ¤Ґ«Ґ­Ёп; ЇаҐ¤Ї®« Ј Ґвбп "extern" б ў®§ўа в®¬ вЁЇ  "int"
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\dlbotov\appdata\local\progra
ms\python\python38\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\dlbotov\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Progr
am Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x64"
 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_rle build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\ext/rle.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\rle.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\ext
\rle.cp38-win_amd64.lib
    LINK : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "PyInit_rle"
    build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\ext\rle.cp38-win_amd64.lib : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\dlbotov\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dlbotov\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i13r_
bk2\\rdpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dlbotov\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i13r_bk2\\rdpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close
();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dlbotov\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-eexckv_3\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\
dlbotov\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\rdpy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

how can I solve the problem with installing this module?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Russian error messages are not helpful at the English-only site. Please switch locale to `C` or `en_US`, repeat the command and rewrite the error message.

Comment: The latest [`rdpy` 1.3.2](https://pypi.org/project/rdpy/#history) was released at May 21, 2015. There're [binary installers](https://pypi.org/project/rdpy/1.3.2/#files) but only for Python 2.7. I'm not sure the code is compatible with Python 3. Try Python 2.7.